# Run pdflatex from external application

Tags: pdftex, terminal-output

I use a Mac.  When I open up the Terminal and run commands like `pdflatex Preface.tex`, all is well.  I'd like, however, to trigger this command from within MatLab.  When I do so, it doesn't recognise "pdflatex".  I'm guessing I need to reference it in a more complex way.  Does anyone know how this could be done please?

Comment: if `pdflatex` is in your path and `Preface.tex` is the the current (matlab) directory I would expect `system('pdflatex Preface')` to work

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that to work too.  :)  When doing a similar thing with OpenOffice, I had to supply a full address for the OpenOffice app (\Users\etc.), but I'm not sure how to generate the same thing in the case of pdflatex.

Comment: if it is in your path i don't see why ot shouldn't work, you can presumably type `which pdflatex` in a terminal window to get the full path to pdflatex

Comment: That's done the job.  Great; thanks!  (/usr/texbin/pdflatex)